# Vertical lines are disjointed in urxvt

Tags: terminal, fonts, rxvt

I'm using Debian testing (stretch) with i3 running urxvt with Source Code Pro (a TTF font).

MOC (an ncurses program) as it appeared last week:
[image]

And now - notice the vertical lines:
[image]

I can "solve" the issue by reducing urxvt's lineSpace to 0, but I want that line spacing - and it worked before.

Any ideas what could cause this? urxvt bug? x11 font rendering bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `URxvt.skipBuiltinGlyphs` is set to `true` in `~/.Xresources`, try setting it to `false`. Fixed it for me.